# How to detect (physical) disconnect when using a bidirectional stream in Grpc

Tags: c++, timeout, grpc

I am using the synchronous C++ API of Grpc to send messages over a bidirectional stream that needs to be kept open indefinitely.

Right now, if I pull the cable between server & client, the `Write` and `Read` calls on that stream will block for about 15 minutes on both sides before returning `false`.

How do I set the timeout of `Read`and `Write` to something less than 15 minutes?

---

I am starting the Server with:

```
ServerBuilder srvBuilder;

srvBuilder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS, 2000);
srvBuilder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
srvBuilder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_BDP_PROBE, 1);
srvBuilder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONNECTION_IDLE_MS , 1000);

srvBuilder.AddListeningPort("0.0.0.0:50505", grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
srvBuilder.RegisterService(&testService);
```

Using Grpc 1.10.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score -1):

You can set the deadline on the RPC by calling set_deadline on the ClientContext before the call.

UPDATE - I apologize for the misunderstanding. 
GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS is exactly what you want. The reason why it's not working as intended is probably related to the way you are making the reads and writes.

Comment: A deadline would *always* terminate the stream when it is exceeded. Since the stream is kept open indefinitely/forever a deadline on ClientContext would almost always terminate the stream too early.

Comment: GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS is not detecting if network gets disconnected after connection established once. The stream is kept opened, status error_message.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md helps explain how keepalives can be set up. The args help configure whether we want keepalive pings to be sent in absence of active streams or if there are no data frames being sent.

Comment: @YashTibrewal it's a good link. However where should we place the check itself? I am placing the channel arguments on client and the same arguments on server builder, however this does not change anything it seems. How can I detect that actually the client is no longer available is there any code example for that check?